# unable to push image into emulator

Tags: android, image, gallery, emulation

I looked at the other question on how to insert image into android emulator. However i attempt this method.

1. Run the emulator
2. go to the ddms and click the sdcard folder
3. push file and select the image i want to insert into the folder

Here is the error

```
[2013-05-08 10:59:00 - ddms] transfer error: Read-only file system
[2013-05-08 10:59:00] Failed to push selection: Read-only file system
```

I have looked at other tutorial and most of them are able to push image into the sdcard file before proceeding to devtool. However, i'm stuck at pushing picture into files

Comment: Could you post the exact command you're using to push the file? Also, can you give the command "adb shell df"?

Comment: i did not type any command. as stated above, i just went into ddms, select the sdcard folder then click the push icon and receive the error above.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you even have an sdcard? If it's an emulator, you probably don't. If that's the case, then the mountpoint `/sdcard` will exist, but it's just an empty directory and part of the `/` filesystem, which will be read-only.

Comment: i'm able to see my sdfolder in the ddms. I also created a "virtual" sd in the emulator so i guess it could be an empty directory. How do i get a mountpoint?

Comment: @user2316009 Please try starting the emulator, when the launcher is up open the `Setting` App and go to `Storage`. Did you see a section for SD Card listing its total and available space?

Comment: i'm using 4.2.2 emulator and when i attempt to click the storage in the setting app, they force close my setting app.

Answer (score 0):

if there exists an sdcard try this command

**adb push somepathtofile /sdcard/**

Comment: type this command in you command prompt(windows) or a terminal as you may call it in a unix/linux system..for it to run make adb is set in your path